# Invoking methods through reflection with variable amount of arguments

Tags: java, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter, when i go to a URI `example.com/index.php/blog/showitem/253`, it loads up the controller `blog` and executes the method `showitem(253)`.

Is something like this possible with Reflection in Java. For example, i have a method `loadController(String controllerName, String method, Objects args...)`, which initializes the correct controller, with the correct method, and with a variable amount of arguments.

I know i can initialize class from strings, invoke methods, but i'm stuck at variable amount of arguments. This is what i have now:

```
public static void switchController(String controllerName, String methodName, Object ... args)
{
try {
    Class controller = Class.forName("director.controllers." + controllerName);
    Method method = controller.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, Object[].class);
    method.invoke(controller.newInstance(), args);
```

What i want is that i can to load the `NewsController` with the `showOne(int id)` method like this:

```
switchController("NewsController", "showOne", 124);
```

Is this possible and if yes, how?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: I can invoke the method, but only without variable arguments. See my edited example of what i'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JavaDoc for Method

> Individual parameters are automatically unwrapped to match primitive formal parameters, and both primitive and reference parameters are subject to method invocation conversions as necessary.

So you should be able to wrap it around an Integer object and invoke it. That should work.